# How to use the data in Promise & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I use Promise + ajax load data to my page.

```
function $myAjax(url, callback) {
   let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "GET",
           data: "data",
           async:false, 
           cache: false,
           success: function(resp) {
              callback(resp);
              resolve();
           },
           failure: function(xhr) {
              reject();
           }
      });
 });
 return p;
}

$myAjax('api/2006.json', function(resp1){
       mapRender('svg1',resp1,'#b4cdff');
}).then(function() {
       return $myAjax('api/2010.json', function(resp2) {
           mapRender('svg2',resp2,'#b4cdff');
       }); 
}).then(function() {
         //...  and so on
})
```

But I have problem to get out the `resp1` and `resp2` from this function, except the `mapRender` I need the resp1 & resp2  to do something, and the "something" is not suitable inside the `$myAjax`.

I try to push the `resp` in array.

```
$myAjax('api/2006.json', function(resp1) {
         array.push(resp1)
         mapRender('svg1',resp1,'#b4cdff');
})
console.log(array)
```

`console.log(array)` => show the data, but with a icon "value below was evaluated just now"

`console.log(array[0])` => undefined

What's wrong with it? 
And How can I get the resp form the `$myAjax` ?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by **"something" is not suitable inside the $myAjax`**

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a terrible practice and is deprecated by browsers. You should be seeing a warning in browser console about the deprecation and pay attention to that warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A far more efficient way to do this would be use the `$.ajax` promise itself along with `Promise.all()` where you would have access to all the responses

```
var svgData =[
   {url:'api/2006.json', selector: 'svg1'},
   {url:'api/2010.json', selector: 'svg2'}
];

var promises = svgData.map(function(item) {
  // return the ajax promise
  return $.getJSON(item.url).then(function(res) {
    // add the data to svgData object
    item.data = res;

  })
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
  svgData.forEach(function(item) {
    // do what you need with each item here
    mapRender(item.selector, item.data, '#b4cdff');
  });
}).catch(function(err) {
  alert('Something went wrong with one of the requests');
})
```